# USB 3.1 Gen 2 hub for 2016 MacBook Pro

Tags: usb, hub

Are there any USB 3.1 Gen 2 hubs in existence? There seem to be lots of options that are USB-C on the computer-end, but provide only USB 3.0 ports for the peripherals. Do I really have to buy an expensive Thunderbolt dock if all I want are a few USB 3.0 and two USB 3.1 Gen 2 ports?

Ideally, it would also have a HDMI (or DisplayPort) connection and power pass through.

I've found among others the following products (none of which has USB 3.1 Gen 2 output)

- [Satechi Slim](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01J4BO0X8)
- [HyperDrive GN22B](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JQOSP84)
- [HooToo UC001B](http://www.hootoo.com/ht-uc001-usb-type-c-hub-charging-hdmi-apple-pd.html)
- [Sandberg](https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/sandberg-usb-c-dock-3ports-usb-hub-5747671?tagIds=77-530)
- [Arc Hub](http://www.bourgedesign.com)
- [nonda](https://www.nonda.co/products/usb-c-hub-for-apple-new-macbook-12-plus) (apparently a failed kickstarter)

Comment: What are the additional 3.1 ports going to be used for. Would it be acceptable if they had lower bandwidth and maximum wattage?

Comment: You could use a male USB 3.0 to female USB 3.1.

Comment: I just thought if I'm going to buy a USB hub, it should have one or two new connectors as well (to future-proof my purchase)... but seems like the only such hub you can currently buy is inside the new [LG displays](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HKMY2LL/A/lg-ultrafine-4k-display)...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any devices that can use USB3.1gen2 potential, so if USB3.1gen1 is OK for you, you should take a look at Dell D6000 docking station: http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-universal-dock-d6000/apd/452-bcyt/pc-accessories

It has:

- 1x USB 3.1gen1 type-C port
- 4x USB 3.1gen1 type-A port
- 2x DP port (5k capable)
- 1x HDMI port
- RJ45 (Ethernet) port
- 3.5mm combo jack for headphones/microphone
- power delivery

And probably it is still cheaper than Thunderbolt dock

Answer (score 1):

I've seen only one so far, Bourge Design's Arc Hub:

https://www.bourgedesign.com/archub

I don't believe the hub is available yet, but it's scheduled for release within the next couple of months.

Unfortunately, it's not suitable for my own needs, as the device's two type-C ports are apparently for charging only--no data. I also want "Gen. 2" type-A ports; the Arc seems to feature type-A Gen. 1 (USB 3.0).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.lindy.co.uk/usb-thunderbolt-c4/4-port-usb-3-1-gen-2-type-c-hub-p11211

> Provides 4 USB 3.1 Gen 2 SuperSpeed+ ports with data rates up to 10Gbps
>
> Allows connection of 2 Type A and 2 Type C peripherals

https://www.iogear.com/product/GUH3C22P/ is not so explicit but it does say 10 gbit/s.

Coolgear has tons https://www.coolgear.com/product-category/usb-c-products/usb-c-hubs